# Convert Templates from Delphi 7 to Delphi 10 Seatle

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-10-seattle, code-conversion

My company migrated from Delphi 7 to Delphi XE3 last year, and finally to Delphi 10 Seattle this year, one of the changes that affected me the most was loosing my old code templates, is there a way to convert the old template system from Delphi 7 to the XML template system used on Delphi 10 Seattle?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there doesn't seem to be an existing tool to migrate those Templates. You'll have to do it by hand or write yourself a little tool which does the job.